# How will a promisified mysql module work with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to work with MySQL in NodeJS. My entire app is built with promises, so I want to promisify the `mysql` module as well.

So I have this:

```
Promise = require('bluebird');
var mysql = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql'));
```

Now, according to their API, the `connect()` method accepts a single parameter, an `err` callback to be called in case of connection error. My question is, how does that translate to promises?

Will the promise be resolved on error? Will it be rejected? Will I need to `.catch()` it perhaps? How does that work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a method is a node "errback" with a single argument - it will be resolved with no parameters in the `then` or alternatively be rejected with the `err` passed to it. In the case of promisification, you can catch it with `.error` or use a catch with `Promise.OperationalError`.

Here is a simple approach:

```
function getConnection(){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'me',
      password : 'secret'
    });
    return connection.connectAsync().return(connection); // <- note the second return
}

getConnection().then(function(db){
    return db.queryAsync(....);
}).error(function(){
   // could not connect, or query error
});
```

If this is for managing connections - I'd use `Promise.using` - here is a sample from the API:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
// uncomment if necessary
// var Promise = require("bluebird");
// Promise.promisifyAll(mysql);
// Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
// Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Pool").prototype);
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'example.org',
    user: 'bob',
    password: 'secret'
});

function getSqlConnection() {
    return pool.getConnectionAsync().disposer(function(connection) {
        try {
            connection.release();
        } catch(e) {};
    });
}

module.exports = getSqlConnection;
```

Which would let you do:

```
Promise.using(getSqlConnection(), function(conn){
    // handle connection here, return a promise here, when that promise resolves
    // the connection will be automatically returned to the pool.
});
```

Comment: is there a way to make async query like getConnectionAsync(), which i can call in promise.using function. or i have to create new promise inside promise.using().