# Promise, return result for .then function

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm using bluebird for my node server and mysql.
I have a few questions. There are function inside first module

```
this.__proto__.getPerson = function (personId) {
    promise.using(db_conn.getSqlConnection(), function (conn) {
        var q = 'SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE person_id = ' + conn.escape(personId) + ';';
        return conn.queryAsync(q);
    })
        .spread(function (rows, fields) {
            return rows;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            throw new Error(err.message, err.code);
        });
};
```

How to promisify mysql i learned from [How will a promisified mysql module work with NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797314/how-will-a-promisified-mysql-module-work-with-nodejs).

question 1: Can I return from module promisifyed object, or I have to do:

```
var dbPerson = new mPerson();
promise.promisifyAll(dbPerson);
```

in every new module where I need the Person.

question 2: How can i receive data from function above, when i do so, i'm getting nothing:

```
dbPerson.getPersonAsync(personId).then(function(rowPerson){
            console.log(rowPerson);
        });
```

UPD: When I'm calling

```
dbPerson.getPersonAsync(personId)
```

I'm getting result inside `.spread`

UPD 2: I got this

```
console.log(dbPerson.getPersonAsync(personId));

{ _bitField: 0,
 _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
 _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
 _promise0: undefined,
 _receiver0: undefined,
 _settledValue: undefined,
 _boundTo: undefined }
```

Resolved: I removed this line
`promise.promisifyAll(dbPerson);`

I think this is because the `dbPerson.getPerson(personId)` already returns a `promise`

Comment: Why are you catching the error if you're not handling it? Also, you can shorten your `.spread` to `.get(0)`.

Comment: You're missing a `return` before the `using`.