# Node, Bluebird Promises, MySQL, and the need for a stiff drink

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bluebird

I'm struggling to implement Bluebird promises with MySql. I think I'm close, but my problems are starting to compound and I could use some help getting back on track. I had this code all working with callbacks, but I have jacked it up with promises.

The current problem is that it doesn't like the "then" on my query, as in:

```
conn.query("DO DB STUFF").then(function(result){});
```

First, I have a connection.js file that looks like this. I've added some comments in the code.

```
(function () {
var mysql = require("mysql");

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: "localhost",
    user: "myuser",
    password: "password",
    database: "dbName"
});

// stole this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797314/how-will-a-promisified-mysql-module-work-with-nodejs
exports.getConnection = function(){
    return pool.getConnectionAsync().disposer(function(connection){
        try{
            connection.release();
        } catch (e) {}
    });
};
})();
```

Then I have a "db access" file that looks like this:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Pool").prototype);
var connection = require("./connection");
var common = require("../../domain/common");

exports.isKnownBadTicker = function (stockSymbol) {
    if (stockSymbol == null) { return false; }
    else {
        var ticker = common.standardizeStockSymbol(stockSymbol);
        var query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM BadTicker WHERE Symbol = '" + ticker + "';";
        // it doesn't like the conn.query(query).then . . . says that "then" is not valid, and so I tried to just return the response of the query - which also doesn't work.
        Promise.using(connection.getConnection(), function (conn) {
            return conn.query(query)[0]["count"] > 0;
            // conn.query(query).then(function (result) {
            //  return result[0]["count"] > 0;
            // });
        });
    }
};
```

I feel like I'm close, but I just can't quite put it together. Can anyone help me straighten this mess out?

Also, I'm not sure I'm doing some other things right, like, can I return a boolean in a function that also returns promises? Feel free to straighten me out if you see that I've gone all whacky. Any help is appreciated.

Vic

Comment: What do you think this `Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);` accomplishes?  You aren't saving any return value from the `require()` operation so it makes me wonder what you think the result of this operation is?

Comment: Took that code from here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyallobject-target--object-options---object. That doesn't mean I'm using it correctly, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `promisifyAll` asynchronous functions got they promisifyed siblings with `Async` suffix. So that you have to use `queryAsync` rather then `query`

```
conn.queryAsync("DO DB STUFF")
  .then(function(result){
    // dont forget here that result is an array
  });
```

Promisifying in second connection example is ok (my version even bit uglier)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mysql = require('mysql');
Promise.promisifyAll(mysql.Connection.prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql/lib/pool').prototype);
```

Getting connection in `mysql` module is sinchronous rather then asynchronous. I think it was done this way for simplification, but now it makes things more confusing. So when you call to `mysql.createPool` you dont have to wait and can work with returned `pool` instantly - `mysql` module will store you queries and execute it when connection will be really  established.

```
/* store this pool in a good place - you have to reuse it. */
var pool = mysql.createPool(credentials); 
/* you could also create connection like this 
   var conn = mysql.createConnection(credentials);
   , but pull is better when you want to do many queries at a time */
```

Now you able to do promisifyed queries with your `pool` like this

```
pool.queryAsync("DO DB STUFF")
  .then(function(result){
    // dont forget here that result is an array
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure it out either!
Closest I got was something like:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");    
var mysql = require("mysql");
var pool = mysql.createPool({
 connectionLimit: 10,
 host: "localhost",
 user: "myuser",
 password: "password",
 database: "dbName" });
pool.query = Promise.promisify(pool.query);
pool.query("DO DB STUFF")
  .spread(function(rows,fields){
    //access your rows here
    });
```

The catch was that fields was being appended to the rows array, so you needed to use .spread.

However, this whole thing made me very uncomfortable that I had no clue how to use this, so I looked at knex which is just a query builder and supports promises natively.